# Expression to use after talking to someone after a long time

Tags: grammar, expressions, idiomatic-language

Oftentimes, on social media, you run into classmates and teachers from olden days. So how do you express that it is heartwarming to be able to speak to them again after a very long time.

Is saying this grammatically correct?

> It's wonderful to be talking to you after such a long while.

Is this an idiomatic expression?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Long time no see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_time_no_see) is idiomatic in this situation, even if it uses grammatically incorrect English.